# ClassNotFound Exception while inflating View in a AlertBox

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to inflate a XML(Layout) inside an AlertBox.

Here is the XML that I want to inflate...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update_information" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chbDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't Show Again"
        android:checked="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ok" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code I am using to inflate the XML...

```
private void display_Update_Info() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater in = new LayoutInflater(this) {

            @Override
            public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }//This code is auto generated. I have no idea what is this...
        };

        final View update = in.inflate(R.layout.updateinformation, null);


        AlertDialog.Builder updateInfo = new Builder(this);
        updateInfo.setView(update);
        updateInfo.show();

    }
```

Here is the Logcat trace...

```
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree/com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class CheckBox
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class CheckBox
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree.MainActivity.display_Update_Info(MainActivity.java:469)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:160)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     ... 11 more
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.CheckBox in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree-1.apk]
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
03-12 16:15:38.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9021):     ... 19 more
```

Also if someone can tell me, what is the use of the auto generated code...

```
@Override
public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
```

I get a force close when I am trying to run the application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
   LayoutInflater in = new LayoutInflater(this) {

        @Override
        public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }//This code is auto generated. I have no idea what is this...
    };
```

use this

```
   LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();
```

and for the second part see the api docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#cloneInContext(android.content.Context).